# Click event information in context menu callback

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

There is a possibility to create custom items for viewer's context menu and callback can be registered ('target' property). But click event doesn't passed inside this callback - I need it to get 'ctrl' key state.
To fix that I have to override Autodesk.Viewing.Private.ContextMenu.prototype.addCallbackToMenuItem method as 'dirty solution'.
Is there any other solution?
P.S. Or could you pass 'event' inside 'target' callback inside 'addCallbackToMenuItem' method out-of-the-box? It is not a big change, but it is useful to process meta buttons state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the hold up is for your need here?

When you register the custom context menu you have access to original mouse event as well as the key press status off the `status` object:

```
NOP_VIEWER.registerContextMenuCallback('MyExtensionName', function (menu, status) {

         menu.push({
              title: 'context menu name',
              target: function () {
                  //access mouse event via "status.event"
         }});

      })
```

**EDIT**
The same event object is available with `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerObjectContextMenu.buildMenu`

```
ViewerObjectContextMenu.prototype.buildMenu = function (event, status) {
...
```

Comment: thanks, Bryan! I need my own context menu (with extra logic inside the overridden  'buildMenu' method), plus I need to add my menu items in certain positions (not to the end), so 'registerContextMenuCallback' is not the case, unfortunately...

Comment: Then probably better off to subscribe to right clicks and build your own context menu from there - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html)

Comment: Ok, I will try it. But generally, I like the current solution with extended Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerObjectContextMenu. The only missing thing is passing 'event' as argument into 'target' callback. I will appreciate it if you add it in the next release.

Comment: The same event object is available when you call `buildMenu(event, status)`

Comment: Bryan, definitely, it is passed inside 'buildMenu', but inside this method, I can only populate a menu with items, and later 'target' callback of the menu item will be called without passing 'event' (this is a thing I am asking to fix).

Comment: That's not something to *fix* because if you are after the click event on the menu item itself then it's not captured by design (and hence better off implement your own) - if you are after the clicks on the canvas then you already have them ...

Comment: Maybe I am confused a bit, but click for opening the menu is the first click (and this event is passed into 'buildMenu' method, it's ok), but click on the menu item is the second (new one) click, and this event is not passed into 'target' callback. To get this functionality I have to override 'addCallbackToMenuItem' method ('target' callback is triggered inside it on menu item click)

Comment: Yes you are doing the right thing - like I said the *second click* on the menu items is not captured by design